# Swapping of the RAM while Shuffling in HADOOP

Tags: hadoop

I work with hadoop 1.1.1. My project is  processing more than 6000 documents. My cluster contains 2 nodes: master(CPU:COREi7, RAM:6G) and slave(CPU:COREi3, RAM:12G). The number of MAPPER is 16. When I assign the number of REDUCER more than 1(e.i. 2,...,16) at the phase of shuffling the RAM begins to SWAP and this causes a significant reduction on my system speed.

How can I stop the RAM from swapping?
What is kept in RAM in the process between MAP and REDUCE?
Is there any reference?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you got your jvm flags set to in `mapred-site.xml` (`mapred.child.java.opts`, `mapred.map.child.java.opts` and `mapred.reduce.child.java.opts`)? Also what are the maximum number of map and reduce tasks configured for each node (again in `mapred-site.xml`)

Comment: in master: `mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2g` , `mapred.tasktracker.map.task.maximum=8` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.task.maximum=8`.And in slave `mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2g` , `mapred.tasktracker.map.task.maximum=4` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.task.maximum=4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So on the master:

- 6G physical RAM;
- 2G allocated per process;
- 8 mappers and 8 reducers can run concurrently;
- 8x2 + 8x2, 32G memory required if all tasks are maxed out - over 5x your physical amount.

On the slave:

- 12G physical RAM;
- 2G allocated per task;
- 4 mappers, 4 reducers;
- 4x2 + 4x2, 16G memory required - 50% more than physical.

Now if you're only running a single job at a time, you can set the slowstart configuration property to 1.0 to ensure that the mappers and reducers don't run concurrently and that will help, but you're still maxed out on the master.

I suggest you reduce either the memory allocation to 1G (if you really want that many map / reduce slots on each node), or reduce the maximum number of tasks for both nodes, such that you're closer to the physical amount (if running maxed out).

Comment: Also you can set mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps to 1.00, it means that reducers will wait for all mappers to complete, thus there's no reducers and mappers run in parallel. This can reduce the memory demand.